# Reason for P-MOSFET between the charge N- FET and charge pin of bq76930

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

I am currently working on a final year project which is a device like a power-bank, but this will be able to charge both phones and laptops.

After a lot reading and research I finally considered using bq76930 (a BMS chip from TI), I will connect lithium ion batteries in series and parallel to meet up with my desired voltage and capacity.

The problem I am currently facing is why they have to connect P-channel MOSFET (i.e., Q12) between the charge pin and N-channel MOSFET for discharge as shown in the circuit. I cut a part from one there documents that seems to give the answer but am I didn't understand really well (as a newbie).

I would appreciate if someone can explain it to me in simple way, and if you can suggest resources or simulation platform to understand it better.

[image: charge discharge protection1]

<sub>Source: [Texas Instruments - Design Guide: TIDA-00449 - 10s battery pack monitoring, balancing, and comprehensive protection, 50-A discharge reference design (TIDUAR8C)](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduar8c/tiduar8c.pdf)</sub>

[image: explanation part from bq76930 documentation]

<sub>Source: [Texas Instruments - bq769x0 Family Top 10 Design Considerations (SLUA749A)](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua749a/slua749a.pdf)</sub>

Comment: HGO - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked for online material (see the linked rule regarding books etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source details for both images & added them for you (please change the links if you copied from different documents). For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @SamGibson that's exactly where I got it from. Noted

Answer (score 1):

Did you see Figure 8-2 from the [Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76930.pdf?ts=1694087973296)?

That includes an explanation of the transistor in question.
[image: Figure 8-2]

Comment: Yes, Thanks for this, I guess I should have shared this instead, are they considering the Vss as the BAT- or Gnd.

Comment: @HGO They're considering Vss to mean the IC pin labelled Vss.